# xcode ios: set cell image dimension

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm loading a set of images from my web server to be displayed in the cell on the right. However, the image comes in different sizes so they look un-even when the list is shown. Is there anyway that I can set the image into a fixed size like 100 x 80 ?

My code is as follow for this section:

```
cell.lotImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blankthumbnail.png"];
cell.lotImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
    //load image from web server
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/images/%@", user.url, lotPhoto[row]];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strURL ];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // let's make sure the cell is still visible (i.e. hasn't scrolled off the screen)
        mainTableCell *cell = (mainTableCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell)
        {
            cell.lotImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            cell.lotImageView.image =image;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Best tutorial to resize image with expected dimensions : http://mobiledevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-scale-an-image-using-an-objective-c-category.html

Comment: Add a frame to your imageView cell.lotImageView setFrame:CGrectMake(0,0,100,80)];

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can achieve your desired size for your image. You can put the below function in your Application Delegate and can use throughout your application. Here's the code:

```
+(UIImage *) resizeImage:(UIImage *)orginalImage resizeSize:(CGSize)size {

    CGFloat actualHeight = orginalImage.size.height;
    CGFloat actualWidth = orginalImage.size.width;
    if(actualWidth <= size.width && actualHeight<=size.height){
        return orginalImage;
        //NSLog(@"hi thassoods");
    }
    float oldRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
    float newRatio = size.width/size.height;
    if(oldRatio < newRatio){
        oldRatio = size.height/actualHeight;
        actualWidth = oldRatio * actualWidth;
        actualHeight = size.height;
    }
    else {
        oldRatio = size.width/actualWidth;
        actualHeight = oldRatio * actualHeight;
        actualWidth = size.width;
    }
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,actualWidth,actualHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [orginalImage drawInRect:rect];
    orginalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return orginalImage;
}
```

But yeah, if the new size specified by you is not proportionate to the original size of your image, then it might be possible that your image resolution will not stay proper.

All the best!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to resize your image. This code made this :

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image convertToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return destImage;
}
```

Comment: you mean just put this code on the .m file? No need to call it ?

Comment: Thats a method so you need to call in your case add this method in .m and change line UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; to UIImage *image = [self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]] convertToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 80)];

Comment: If that doesn't worked let the code and add after line cell.lotImageView.image =image; this code cell.lotImageView setFrame:CGrectMake(cell.lotImageView.frame.origin.x,cell.lotImageView.frame.origin.y,100,80)]; normally with this you have the size of your UIImageView and your UIImage at the good size.